# Error when starting ghci with option -fexternal-interpreter -prof

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying to see callstacks as explained here, https://simonmar.github.io/posts/2016-02-12-Stack-traces-in-GHCi.html

Unfortunately I am getting an error right after ghci starts :

```
C:\Users\sandwood>ghci -fexternal-interpreter -prof
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Access violation in generated code when reading 00000001001a0418
```

Any clue of what to do ?

Comment: The title says `-fproof`, but the code says `-prof`.

Comment: Corrected, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known issue, see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14271
Looks like it occurs only on Windows.

Unfortunately I don't have anything to add, there is no known workaround.